# How to subtract rows from first row, per subject?

Tags: arrays, sas, rows, subtraction

I have subject ids with measurements at different ages. It looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgW69.jpg)

```
Subject Gender Datasource MHGCAT_COD_4 MHGCAT_COD_6 MHGCAT_COD_11 age_ga
124       1       1         21            122          1212         38
124       1       1         21            122          1212         39
124       1       1         21            122          1212         41
124       1       1         21            122          1212         43
125       1       1         21            122          1212         33
125       1       1         21            122          1212         38
```

I want to create an extra column that computes like this:

```
Subject Gender Datasource MHGCAT_COD_4 MHGCAT_COD_6 MHGCAT_COD_11 age_ga  window
124       1       1         21            122          1212         38      0
124       1       1         21            122          1212         39      1
124       1       1         21            122          1212         41      3
124       1       1         21            122          1212         43      5
125       1       1         21            122          1212         33      0 
125       1       1         21            122          1212         38      5
```

I am using SAS to do this. THanks!

Image attached in case the format goes haywire.

Comment: Explain in more detail the logic for the new variable. Show the code that you tried.

Comment: The new variable puts the first age_ga value as the baseline and all other values after that are post baseline. The data is already sorted by age_ga. I subtracted row 2 -  row 1 but I cannot ask the code to start the cycle again at every new subject id to do the same. So, window, row 1 = 0..window, row 2 =  age_ga row 2 -  age_ga row 1.....window, row 5 = 0, window row 6 = age_ga row 6 - age_ga row 5..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BY variable processing.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by subject age_ga ;
  if first.subject then index_age = age_ga ;
  retain index_age ;
  window = age_ga - index_age;
run;
```

Comment: This works! It would be good to drop index_age instead of retaining it. Thank you for the solution!